# time settings in NetCDF file get corrupted by my ArcMap-Program

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, netcdf

I downloaded a NetCDF-file from here: http://eca.knmi.nl/download/ensembles/downloadchunks.php (0.25 reg grid, years 1995-2016, tn), but the time is not displayed correctly when viewing it with ArcMap 10.4 on my laptop (advanced licence) or computer (basic licence):
Instead of giving back each day of all the years, it gives me every 8 Seconds of the first three days. It somehow is reading the date wrongly.

The same file worked fine on the PC of a colleague. Does anyone have a guess, what the problem might be?

I might have corrupted the settings when trying to find out how to work with NetCDF-Files, but how can I straighten that out again?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the time-settings on my desktop (Windows 7) to US settings (system -> regions and language). Changing how to show the date seemed to be enough. Time is still shown german-style, but it's working fine now.